# Templating does not work in Airflow's on_failure_callback

Tags: python, airflow

Issue: Templates in operators used in `on_failure_callback` are not rendered.

```py
def report_failure(context):
    send_email = EmailOperator(
        task_id="email_failed",
        to=emailreceipients,
        subject="{{execution_date}}",
        html_content=get_email_body() # Which returns "Body: {{execution_date}}"
    )

    # One solution I tried fails on: AttributeError: 'EmailOperator' object has no attribute 'render_template_fields'
    # Which is weird as this method is present on EmailOperator's base: BaseOperator
    # send_email.render_template_fields(context)

    send_email.execute(context)

default_args = {
    'on_failure_callback': report_failure
}
```

The email getting sent includes literally `{{execution_date}}` instead of rendered value.

In this simple case I could format these templated strings in place using `.format(**context)`, but I have this email sending reused in other places where `context` is not available and templating works fine.

The bigger goal is to have this "error handler" fired anytime any steps of the DAG (or its subdags) fail.

Comment: `send_email.render_template_fields(context)` did not work because I browsed version 1.10.6, whereas in Docker there was 1.10.4.

Answer (score 3):

After multiple tries with different approaches I found following solutions working:

### Solution A: Don't use on_failure_callback, but create tasks with trigger_rule='all_failed'/'one_failed;

Is what Jacob proposed on Airflow's Slack and it seems to work fine. It's conceptually the easiest IMHO.

```
status_failed = SimpleHttpOperator(
    trigger_rule='all_failed', # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html
    task_id='updateStatus',
    ...
)
email_failed = EmailOperator(
    trigger_rule='all_failed',
)

start_task >> do_the_thing >> status_success >> email_success
# Handling errors in case any job fails
email_success >> email_failed
email_success >> status_failed
```

Exampl: Successful run that sets whole DAG's status as "success" and error handlers as skipped.
[image: successful run]

### Solution B: Use on_failure_callback and render templates manually

As Ash said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078018/803174) `The reason templates don't work there is that templates are not rendered by execute() but before hand.` I found the following solution working:

```
def report_failure(context):
    send_email = EmailOperator(
        task_id="email_failed",
        start_date=datetime(2015, 12, 1), # Any date in the past, if you won't set it you will get an error
        to=emailreceipients,
        subject="{{execution_date}}",
        html_content=get_email_body() # Which returns "Body: {{execution_date}}"
    )

    # Set DAG, otherwise we will get errors
    send_email.dag = context['dag']

    # Manually render templates
    # send_email.render_template_fields(context) # Working in Airflow 1.10.6
    # send_email.html_content = send_email.render_template('', send_email.html_content, context) # Working in Airflow 1.10.4
    # Looking at codebase seems to be working in both versions
    send_email.html_content = send_email.get_template_env().from_string(send_email.html_content).render(**context)

    send_email.execute(context)
```

The issue with it is that it seems that those functions change very often so it might be hard to update it.

### Solution C: format message using `context` variable

As Jacob suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60077286/803174)

It does not solve my particular case when the code generating the template is shared with operators not using context. Nevertheless it might be helpful for simpler cases, so I'm posting it here.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing this might work, but you definitely need double curly braces for jinja templating:
`{execution_date}` -> `{{ execution_date }}`

You should also be able to use the context argument to get the execution date:

```py
def report_failure(context):
    send_email = EmailOperator(
        task_id="email_failed",
        to=emailreceipients,
        subject=context['execution_date'],
        html_content="Body: {execution_date}".format(execution_date=context['execution_date'])
    )
```

You also might find this useful:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html

Comment: My mistake while giving this example. I'm using double braces and it doesn't work. I can't / don't want to use `context` argument directly, because email body comes from utility function as I mentioned. I updated the example to be more clear.

Comment: I'm not totally certain `on_failure_callback` is meant for triggering more operators, which is possibly why templating doesn't work. 

I suggest working around this problem by using:
    `format` and `context`, or
    add this EmailOperator to your dag, with trigger_rule `one_failed`

Answer (score 1):

The reason templates don't work there is that templates are not rendered by `execute()` but before hand.

What you need to do to make this work is this

```py
def report_failure(context):
    send_email = EmailOperator(
        task_id="email_failed",
        to=emailreceipients,
        subject="{{execution_date}}",
        html_content=get_email_body() # Which returns "Body: {{execution_date}}"
    )

    send_email.dag = context['dag']
    send_email.start_date = send_email.dag.start_date
    send_email.render_template_fields(context, jinja_env=context['dag'].get_template_env())
    send_email.execute(context)
```

Comment: I received error `Operator <Task(EmailOperator): email_failed> has not been assigned to a DAG yet`. Added `send_email.dag = context['dag']` then got `DAG does not have start_date set` (or similar). I'm trying different methods..

Comment: I needed also to add `start_date=datetime(2015, 12, 1)` to EmailOperator.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the Taskflow API? I have a param "since" which uses the prev_start_date_success timestamp that I want rendered when I email a failure alert (I list files modified since that timestamp).

        since="{{ params.since if params.since is not none else prev_start_date_success or data_interval_end }}"

Answer (score 0):

Need help on rendering the jinja template email ID in the On_failure_callback ..

It works fine with Variable.get('email_edw_alert'), but i don't want to use Variable method to avoid hitting DB

Below is the Dag file

```
import datetime
import os
from functools import partial
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG,Variable
from airflow.contrib.operators.snowflake_operator import SnowflakeOperator
from alerts.email_operator import dag_failure_email


def get_db_dag(
    *,
    dag_id,
    start_date,
    schedule_interval,
    max_taskrun,
    max_dagrun,
    proc_nm,
    load_sql
):

    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': start_date,
        'provide_context': True,
        'execution_timeout': timedelta(minutes=max_taskrun),
        'retries': 0,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3),
        'retry_exponential_backoff': True,
        'email_on_retry': False,
    }


    dag = DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=max_dagrun),
        template_searchpath=tmpl_search_path,
        default_args=default_args,
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup='{{var.value.dag_catchup}}',
        on_failure_callback=partial(dag_failure_email, config={'email_address': '{{var.value.email_edw_alert}}'}),
    )


    load_table = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id='load_table',
        sql=load_sql,
        snowflake_conn_id=CONN_ID,
        autocommit=True,
        dag=dag,
    )

    load_table

    return dag

# ======== DAG DEFINITIONS #

edw_table_A = get_db_dag(
    dag_id='edw_table_A',
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21),
    schedule_interval='0 5 * * *',
    max_taskrun=3,  # Minutes
    max_dagrun=1,  # Hours
    load_sql='recon/extract.sql',
)
```

Below is the python code

```
import logging
from airflow.utils.email import send_email
from airflow.models import Variable

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

TIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

def dag_failure_email(context, config=None):

    config = {} if config is None else config
    task_id = context.get('task_instance').task_id
    dag_id = context.get("dag").dag_id
    execution_time = context.get("execution_date").strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
    reason = context.get("reason")

    alerting_email_address = config.get('email_address')

    dag_failure_html_body = f"""<html>
    <header><title>The following DAG has failed!</title></header>
    <body>
    <b>DAG Name</b>: {dag_id}<br/>
    <b>Task Id</b>: {task_id}<br/>
    <b>Execution Time (UTC)</b>: {execution_time}<br/>
    <b>Reason for Failure</b>: {reason}<br/>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    try:
        if reason != 'dagrun_timeout':
            send_email(
                to=alerting_email_address,
                subject=f"Airflow alert: <DagInstance: {dag_id} - {execution_time} [failed]",
                html_content=dag_failure_html_body,
            )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            f'Error in sending email to address {alerting_email_address}: {e}',
            exc_info=True,
        )
```

I have also tried another way too, even below one is not working

```
 try:
        if reason != 'dagrun_timeout':
            send_email = EmailOperator(
               to=alerting_email_address,
               task_id='email_task',
               subject=f"Airflow alert: <DagInstance: {dag_id} - {execution_time} [failed]",
               params={'content1': 'random'},
               html_content=dag_failure_html_body,
           )
            send_email.dag = context['dag']
            #send_email.to = send_email.get_template_env().from_string(send_email.to).render(**context)
            send_email.to = send_email.render_template(alerting_email_address, send_email.to, context)
            send_email.execute(context)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            f'Error in sending email to address {alerting_email_address}: {e}',
            exc_info=True,
        )
```